# is it possible to iterate and format at the same time with a python 'f' string

Tags: python, string, formatting

Given an array of byte data one can produce concise hex output like this:

```
...
bbuf = [ 133, 53, 234, 241, 0xff, 127, 128,1 ]
print( ''.join(f'{bval:02x}:' for bval in bbuf) )
...
```

'85:35:ea:f1:ff:7f:80:01:'

One can also unpack it using the 'f' string '*' operator:

```
...
print(f'{*bbuf,}')
...
```

'(133, 53, 234, 241, 255, 127, 128, 1)'

Is there a way to unpack and format at the same time? Every syntactic variation I have tried has blown up. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "unpack and format at the same time"? Sorry, I'm just not understanding this.

Comment: There is no " 'f' string '*' operator", you just used a less readable version of `print(f'{tuple(bbuf)}')`.

Comment: `*` is not an "f-string operator", that is mrely the expression `*bbuf,`, which as you will see, creates a tuple from `bbuf`

Comment: In an `f`-string, the code after `{ ` has to be a valid expression that can be evaluated at the time the `f`-string is interpreted. What you are suggesting would require that evaluation to be deferred until after `bbuf` is unpacked into its byte values. So, no way to do what you want.

Comment: My effort was an attempt to make more readable and concise python. So far the python docs have not provided me with the answers I was seeking. You all filled in the voids, thank you.